# Get File by name at specific folder

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to replicate [this](https://yagisanatode.com/2018/10/05/google-apps-script-get-file-by-name-with-optional-parent-folder-crosscheck/) code to fine a specific file by name, by I got error at `var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);` as `Exception: Invalid argument` at `fileName`, but if I entered the fileName`manually as string` "10504-China-ReflectiveTape-NA.jpg"` it is running correctly!
Below the full code:

```
// ****EXAMPLE****
 
//My arguments for the function
var myFileName = "10504-China-ReflectiveTape-NA.jpg";
var myFileParentFolderName = "Catalog";
 
//Run the function
var getFileID = getFileByName(myFileName, myFileParentFolderName);
 
//Check if folder exists
if(getFileID.id === false){ //if file cannot be accurately found.
  Logger.log(getFileID.error); //alert or log error. Give option to try another FileName
}else{
  // If the file ID exists then proceed with the program. 
  Logger.log(getFileID.id);
};
/*
* ****Get File By Name***
*
*param 1: File Name 
*param 2: Parent Folder of File (optional)
*
*returns: Dictionary of file "id" and "error" message {"id": ,"error": }
*  -if there is no error, "id" returns file id and "error" returns false
*  -if there is an error, "id" returns false and "error" returns type of error as a string for user to display or log.
*/

function getFileByName(fileName, fileInFolder){
 
  var filecount = 0;
  var dupFileArray = [];
  var folderID = "";
  
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
  
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    dupFileArray.push(file.getId());
    
    filecount++;
  };
  
  if(filecount > 1){
    if(typeof fileInFolder === 'undefined'){
        folderID = {"id":false,"error":"More than one file with name: "+fileName+". \nTry adding the file's folder name as a reference in Argument 2 of this function."}
    
    }else{
     //iterate through list of files with the same name
     for(fl = 0; fl < dupFileArray.length; fl++){
       var activeFile = DriveApp.getFileById(dupFileArray[fl]);
       var folders = activeFile.getParents();
       var folder = ""
       var foldercount = 0;
       
       //Get the folder name for each file
       while(folders.hasNext()){
         folder = folders.next().getName(); 
         foldercount++;
       };
       
       if(folder === fileInFolder && foldercount > 1){
         folderID = {"id":false,"error":"There is more than one parent folder: "+fileInFolder+" for file "+fileName}
       };
       
       if(folder === fileInFolder){
           folderID = {"id":dupFileArray[fl],"error":false};
           
       }else{
         folderID = {"id":false,"error":"There are multiple files named: "+fileName+". \nBut none of them are in folder, "+fileInFolder}
       };
     };
   };
   
  }else if(filecount === 0){
      folderID = {"id":false,"error":"No file in your drive exists with name: "+fileName};
      
  }else{ //IF there is only 1 file with fileName
    folderID = {"id":dupFileArray[0],"error":false};
    };

  return folderID;
};
```

Comment: You use a block of global variables code. Wrap it around a function and run that particular function. I think this will solve your issue. Let me know if it did. Wrap the code starting from `var myFileName..` until `Logger.log(getFileID.id);};` into a function. And execute only that function from the script editor.

Comment: However, it is a good practice in every programming language to print your variables to see what they contain. Inside the function `getFileByName`  and before `DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);` do `console.log(fileName)` to see if you are getting the expected value and then do `console.log(typeof fileName)` to see if you are getting back a string. You posted almost 100 lines of code but it is difficult/impossible for us to execute it or test it and people might want to close the question as `"needs debugging details"`.

Comment: Thanks @Marios you are correct, it is fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to replicate your issue where you passed a parameter and it fails vs you passed a string and it works.

But it seems that you are running `getFileByName()` directly by default thus it errors out like that.

Place everything else inside a main function and run that function instead.
I'm getting the expected output when I do that using your code.

It should look like this:

[image]

make sure that the chosen function is your main function that calls the getFileByName and just run the code.

Comment: That is exactly what I said in the comment. But nice you put an answer here.

Comment: I was editing and fixing the the formatting, wasn't able to see your comments as soon as possible.

I realized when I saw your comment after posting the answer. great recommendation though on your 2nd comment which is lacking in my answer

Comment: You are good, no worries :) I voted up your answer cause I think it will solve the issue :)

Comment: Thanks, it is done correctly, answer accepted, and voted up as well, welcome to stackoverflow community :)

Comment: I appreciate the understanding @HasanAYousef. You too Marios. Thank you both for the appreciation.